# as3, starting game with adl on mac os, no visual on desktop, context3d error on mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, runtime, stage3d

**Situation**
~~~~~~~~
I'm using the following line to compile my project:

```
amxmlc -debug=true -librarypath+=./vendors/starling.swc -output=build/Main.swf -swf-version=13 src/Main.as
```

The projects works fine in a browser.
Packaging using a self signed certificate with air, then installing the game works also well.

**Problem**
~~~~~~~
I can't run my game simply using adl in the two following situations:

- with desktop profile:

  ```
  adl Game-config.xml (-profile=desktop)
  ```

  Game starts, trace works fine, no errors in logs BUT no visual, not even a window to display a canvas.
- and with mobile profile:

  ```
  adl -profile mobileDevice -screensize 720 Game-config.xml
  ```

  This time I get a window and the canvas, but an error (in the canvas) from stage3D:

  ```
  Context3D error: Error #2008: Parameter profile must be one of the accepted values.
  ```

  Error looked like I didn't allow mobile profile so I added in Game-config.xml:

  ```
  <supportedProfiles>desktop mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
  ```

  Same error.

I searched and tried adl options, but didn't had success.
I also spend some time looking config file documentation and tweaked it but had again no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply don't get it, Now it works.

I used the same command than the day I posted, I have exact same version of air framework, exact same configuration (Game-app.xml) ...

Maybe it was an auto update of adobe or smth ...
Or maybe the god of mighty reboot ...

I heard that if you reboot seven time you can get any wish comes true.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to have two separate configs, one for desktop and another for mobile.

Comment: That is not helping, both configs doesn't work. Looks like you didn't read it well, or maybe did I wrote something ambiguous ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm doomed to use adobe flash projector.